# Word wrap in Firefox

Tags: firefox

The text displayed on several forum sites that I frequently visit does not automatically word wrap in Firefox's window. Rather, it just "runs off" the right end of the window.

I can cause the text to word wrap correctly by maximizing the window and then immediately returning it to its normal size. This lasts until I move to another page, where I then have to repeat this *workaround* to display word wrapped text correctly again.

Does anyone have any ideas for what I can do to make Firefox always automatically word wrap text?

Answer (score 1):

[Try this Word Wrap addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toggle-word-wrap/)

[image]

> Unchecking "Enable Word Wrap" in the Options menu (or pressing the keyboard shortcut) will temporarily turn off word wrapping for the current message - lines will take up the whole width of the composer window, and no line breaks will get added to the outgoing message (with the exception of "hard" line breaks inserted manually).
>
> Checking "Enable Word Wrap" will enable word wrapping again and set it to the standard width (which is modifiable through the "mailnews.wraplength" preference in the Config Editor, the default is 72 characters).

Comment: Welcome @macsit, next time please provide some more information ;-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that add-on sets a wordwrap inside a textarea. I think @AtlantaBill is talking about the forum posts running off to the right.

Comment: macsit, toggling word wrap with Toggle Word Wrap had no effect on a page with which I'm having problems. This forum page consist of multiple, text columns. The whole page extends past the right-hand side of my Firefox window. Interestingly, if I maximize the Firefox window and then immediately restore it to its normal size, Foxfire (or Windows 7) word-wraps the main-text column so that everything fits perfectly in the window. However, as soon as I go to a different page in the same forum, the problem appears again.

Comment: This add-on is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Links to the forum/thread?

Text will generally always wrap. (Larger) pictures are apt to break things though - depending upon the board software & how pics are handled.

If it is just text, again it could be a forum issue, though there are bookmarklets (or extensions) that can be helpful in many situations.